# Date Sorting in Excel PivotTables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable that has a date field in it, call it Mydate.

I have put this as a column label and then grouped the label by Years, Months and Days.

I then have put the years and days in reverse order by clicking on the label and then choosing to Sort Newest to Oldest.

If I then expand the month to show the days and then try to sort the days, the sorting is messed up....it treats the days above 10 as coming before day 2, 3, etc.

Here is what it looks like in the row label section:

```
    -2015  
         -Apr
             9-Apr
             8-Apr
             ...
             2-Apr
             1-Apr
             16-Apr
             15-Apr
             ...
```

Is there any way to fix this in the PivotTable or do I need to make an additional "Day" column to get this to work properly?

EDIT:  These are properly stored as dates and the sorting works properly if I Ungroup the date field and then sort on just the dates without Years or Months.

Comment: enter them as dates, not text.  Enter the "date" Apr 9, 2015. then format it to just show "Apr 9" .... since it's a date, it'll sort like a date.

Comment: Based on the apparent random sorting, are you sure there is no other sort being applied on the actual values instead of the field values?  To test, click on a day `9-Apr` and then re-sort using the top drop down next to "Row Labels".  You also have to apply the sort to each "level" in the row label.  Years, then months, then days.

Comment: @Ditto, You will not get the grouping menu if even one date is stored wrong (as text).  So I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: @Ditto, Byron is correct, these are stored as dates.  If I Ungroup the field so that the Years and Months are not grouped, it will sort them properly.  It only sorts the days incorrectly when the Year and Month groupings are also selected.

Comment: @Byron Yeah, there aren't any other sorts applied.  These are the only rows in the table.  I sorted it on each level...Once I sort the day level after sorting the other two, it does the described sorting.

Comment: @OpiesDad, Very odd.  I get the same errors on random data.  Doesn't seem to matter what happens in the layers above, the days are all over the place.  Appears to be the same issue as here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fd1d887e-f34c-470a-bd65-3725cc168bf3/date-sorting-issue-in-pivot-table?forum=excel

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a good solution other than adding a helper column as suggested in your link and as I was almost resigned to doing to begin with.  Pretty annoying.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem with German Windows and Excel. Seems depending on whether short data format in Control Panel - Clock, Language, and Region - Region and Language provides two digits for the day. Try with `mm/dd/yyyy` there instead of `m/d/yy`.

Comment: @Axel Thanks!  I can verify that this solution works on US Windows and Excel.  Unfortunately, I was working on my project to send this PivotTable to other users and I can't guarantee that their settings are like this.  If you put this in an answer, I'll mark it as correct anyways as I think it could be helpful to people who are making Pivots for their own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short:
The dates in pivot table fields were sorted in text manner, not in date manner, if we sort the pivot table data field with the default sort mechanism of Excel. If there is only one digit for the day, this will not be in right order by date. Whether there is only one digit for the day, depends only on the  locale settings of Windows, not on the date format in Excel.

Long:
We have the short date format in locale settings of Windows to have only one digit for the day. `Control Panel` - `Clock, Language, and Region` - `Region and Language`:

[image]

This is a German Windows. In English Windows it will be `m/d/yy` for example.

Now we have Excel data like this.

[image]

Note that the Excel's date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

We create a pivot table and group that by Year, Month and Day. If we sort the days they will be sorted in text manner. This will not be in right order by date.

[image]

Now we change the short date format in locale settings of Windows to have two digits for the day.

[image]

Again, this is a German Windows. In English Windows it will be `mm/dd/yyyy` for example.

And we refresh the pivot table. Now it will be in right order by date. But it is always nor sorted in text manner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I did some research and found out how to do this in code.  I'll add an answer so that others can use this too.

Answer (score 0):

Axel's answer works, but if you are planning on sending the worksheet to other users, you may not know if they have updated their settings.

Here is code to do this via VBA:

```
Private Declare Function SetLocaleInfo _
  Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetLocaleInfoA" ( _
  ByVal Locale As Long, _
  ByVal LCType As Long, _
  ByVal lpLCData As String) As Boolean

Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()

Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = 31

Private Sub ChangeSettingExample()
'change the setting of the character displayed as the decimal separator.
    Call SetLocalSetting(LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, "MM/dd/yy") 'to change to proper format
    'check your control panel to verify or use the
    'GetLocaleInfo API function
End Sub

Private Function SetLocalSetting(LC_CONST As Long, Setting As String) As Boolean
    Call SetLocaleInfo(GetUserDefaultLCID(), LC_CONST, Setting)
End Function
```

Note:  I modified the code found here: [Control Windows Regional Settings](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/41533-controlling-windows-regional-settings-visual-basic-applications.html) by user Tom Schreiner